# Protractor not able to identify the angularjs button using locator by.partialButtonText or by.buttontext

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, protractor

Angularjs object properties

```
<button class="btn ng-binding" data-ng-click="v.icle(vehidForm.$valid);" tabindex="0"> Continue </button>
```

code used to identify the object

```
element(by.buttonText("Continue"));

or 

element(by.partialButtonText("Continue"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the guesses, but here are things to try:

- use the [`by.xpath` locator](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.By.xpath):

  ```
  element(by.xpath("//button[contains(., 'Continue')]"));
  ```
- check the `data-ng-click` value instead:

  ```
  $('button[data-ng-click="vm.addVehicle(vehicleAddForm.$valid);‌"]');
  $('button[data-ng-click*=addVehicle]');
  ```
- wait for the button [to be present](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.presenceOf):

  ```
  var elm = element(by.partialButtonText("Continue"));
  var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

  browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(elm), 5000);

  elm.click();
  ```

Comment: Yes i am able to identilfy it using                                                                     element(by.xpath('//button[@data-ng-click="vm.addVehicle(vehicleAddForm.$valid);"]')).click();                        but i want to know why it is not identifying using angular specific locators such as element(by.buttonText("Continue"));

Comment: @DilipReddy okay, I would then use `$('button[data-ng-click*=addVehicle]');` - more concise and readable.

Comment: @DilipReddy What does the error say? You also probably can have multiple 'Continue' buttons in your app and trying selecting wrong one as long as 1st one receiving a click

Comment: Yes ,Application has multiple 'Continue' buttons , it is not throwing any error at same time it is not clicking the button in that page